# Can not connect to Postgres from Python

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I created a docker image with Postgres via Dockerfile:

> FROM postgres:9.6-alpine

After I started this docker container, I'm checking that it's up and running using a connection from the different docker container that has pre-installed **psql**:

> docker run -it --rm --link ml-postgres:postgres postgres:12.2-alpine
> psql --dbname mlpython -h postgres -U postgres

The result is that I'm able to connect to the first container with postgres and perform all regular operations with the postgres DB.

Troubles begin when I want to connect to the container with postgres DB from a Python script that I created locally:

```
import psycopg2
    
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    database="mlpython",
    user="postgres",
    password="test",
    port="5431"
)
cur = conn.cursor()
    
cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable LIMIT 10')
cur.close()
```

Here is an error which I get:

```
> psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
>   This probably means the server terminated abnormally    before or while
> processing the request.
```

What do I miss while trying to bootstrap this simple code sample where Python interacts with Postgres?

Comment: When you start the database container, you need a `docker run -p` option for it to be accessible from outside Docker; with that connection string, something like `docker run -p 5431:5432 postgres:9.6-alpine` (the second port number must be the default port 5432 but the first can be anything).

Answer (score 0):

Please read through the [README.md](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md) of a docker image you use. It should answer your questions.
I'm not sure, if you did, because:

1. I see, you started psql - the client. Why, if you're going to connect from python? And have you started the server?
2. I can't see if you exposed any container port to a host machine